# Embedded tumblr image size

Tags: javascript, image, tumblr, image-size

I have just embedded my tumblr into my website (which is not visible to anyone yet), with this code:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.thegoodbad.tumblr.com/js" ></script>`

It worked out, and shows the posts BUT the problem is: it shows all the pictures on the website with a 400px width even though on my tumblr they are bigger.

So far I:

- played around with the photo url, and changed it to high reslolution
- tried to add some css code to my website
- tried to use other tumblr themes with high resolution pictures

I read that tumblr hard-coded the pictures to max. 400px. I don´t know if I actually have to change something in my tumblr code to change the image size output or if I can change this in the code of the new site.

I am kinda new to all of this and so far I managed but now I would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that Tumblr "hard coded" the pictures to a maximum width of 400px, although their documentation says up to 500px. They didn't do this doing CSS; they did it by only serving you the 400px version of the picture, [as seen here](http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lsphpbVgA91qai041o1_400.jpg).

If you apply any CSS to these images to make them bigger, you'll only downgrade the quality of the image.

> [Note:](http://features.tumblr.com/post/1154189/uploading-images-to-use-in-themes) Based on Tumblr’s image resize, you will be limited to an image
>   width of 500px unless you specify the width differently in the IMG
>   tag.

Comment: thanks for your answer! so why is it not even showing the 500px? and so ther eis nothing i can do (add code anywehere ..) to change the 400px width tha i get when i embedd the feed? ...sorry in case you feel like you already answered this.....as said i m just starting to learn to code ;)

Comment: @user2227593  I'm not sure why it's not even showing the 500px. The documentation that I quoted might not apply to the "embed version" that you are using, and that's why you are getting 400 instead of 500. Do you want to make the picture bigger then 400px, even if making it bigger will degrade the quality? If so I can help you with the solution for that. But again, that will degrade the quality of the image - it will make it blurry, pixelated, etc. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: no thanks you i need the pictures sharp for my other website. i guess i ll have to find another solution than tumblr. i just wanted to have a blogfeed with my pictures on my website and this seemed like an easy solution. in case you know another service for that you can let me know. thanks for your answers!

Comment: @user2227593 If you feel that my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark it as answered :) Have you checked out Flickr or Photobucket?